# open Vine profile with username from iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme, vine

I found that `vine://user/907031926412546048` is working.

is there any way to open by username? `vine://user/canaksoy`

or any api call to find username by userid?

Answer (score 1):

I would shy away from hard coding this. Usernames can change instantly and by hard coding it in, you literally would have to push an app update just to correlate to that new username. I think by using a user ID number its guaranteed and leaves no room for error. But if you really don't want to do that here is an alternative:

This is untested on my behalf, but I do know they have custom urls, you might be able to play with this:

https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170806-vine-profile-urls

> A profile URL is a unique Vine profile address accessible from the web. Once you select an available URL you will be able to access your profile by visiting vine.co/[yourURL]. Selecting a custom URL allows you to share your profile easily and makes it easier for others to find and watch the videos you’ve created.

**EDIT** based on the discussion below :

This is why it's important to use unique ID :

A quick search for everyone with the username of Drew Carey:

[image: pic1]

This is why they don't have usernames in my opinion. Because they aren't unique. Even vine utilizes the unique ID when you invite someone to see your vine or profile via text or email. Additionally, when you sign up through twitter it shows your real name. There is too much room for error. I would simply ask the users to enter their custom url if they have one or unique ID until this feature is available publicly.

Comment: my ios app users can add their vine account by manualy entering username. how can I save vine accounts and link to vine app profile page?

now I just open url in safari.

Comment: @CanAksoy even Vine uses the unique user ID # when you use the 'invite via text' option. Your at the mercy of their API, and since they don't have one, it's likely this isn't possible at this point until they see a need for it. Again, my theory is because usernames change, additionally, when you sign up with Twitter it uses your full name. Lots of variables (special characters, spaces, duplicate usernames etc). [This is the extent of their API](https://dev.twitter.com/web/vine/oembed) you could ask users to provide their unique ID and save it for reference, but it's limited at this point

Comment: yes I can see that problems.

https://api.vineapp.com/users/search/canaksoy

maybe with this api link. user can select his account with in listing accounts, then I can get ID of user.